# I am trying to make my first project on vscode and I got this error what can I do

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
int no1,no2,sum;
printf("Enter any two numbers");
scanf("%d%d",&no1,&no2);
sum=no1+no2;
printf ("Sum of the numbers is %d",sum);
}
```

This code is not running taking too much time

Comment: What is `Scan`?

Comment: With this `&no1&no2` you try to put two variables at once as the second parameter. It is telling you to only use one variable.

Comment: I don't know if you just have some typos, but where you want to scan in two integers, your line of code should be changed from "Scan("%d",&no1&no2);" to "scanf("%d %d",&no1, &no2);".  The string literal "%d %d" indicates there will be two values entered on the line.

Comment: Thank you @NoDakker my original one for scan is scanf ("%d%d",& no1 & no2); according to the turboc++ i just did it first time on vscode

Comment: `conio.h` isn't used (that's a good thing) Avoid including it as it is 100% non-portable to anything but DOS/windows. You cannot use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. `if (scanf ("%d%d", &no1, &no2) != 2) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`. Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` [§5.1.2.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1)

Comment: Go download another compiler. Turbo C++ is ancient. So ancient in fact it still uses `<string.h>` for C++. The Borland version was last updated in 1996. Embarcadero last supported a release of the Borland suite in 2010, but was more of a support release rather than an updated feature release. All of which was well before C/C++11 and STL. MinGW64 is fine for a gcc flavor compiler (you can get it bundled with Code::Blocks), or you can download VS2022 for a MS compiler. Both will be light-years ahead of Turbo C/C++.

Comment: Always end your last program output with a `'\n'` character so you code will be POSIX compliant For example `printf ("Sum of the numbers is %d\n",sum);` Otherwise, the code will mess up the next prompt on all flavors of Unix/Linux and Mac.